# Javascript date conversion does not fail

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have an input date string like so "30/09/1992", and I found this code to suit my need. PFB the code.

```
var input1 = "30/09/1992";
var isVaidDate = false;
var actualDate = "";
try{
var pattern = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;
var arrayDate = input1.match(pattern);
var actualDate = new Date(arrayDate[3], arrayDate[2] - 1, arrayDate[1]);
var isVaidDate = typeof dt.getMonth === 'function';
}catch(e){var output1 = false;}
print(isVaidDate);
print(actualDate);
```

The above code works fine but when I set the input as "31/09/1992" or "40/09/1992" I am expecting invalid date to come but I get the below output.

for "31/09/1992":

```
true
Thu Oct 01 1992 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

for "40/09/1992":

```
true
Thu Oct 10 1992 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

How should I get this to fail when i pass these two strings. Thanks. Also what is going on and why it didnt fail, would also be useful :)

Comment: You will have to manually check if `+arrayDate[3] !== date.getFullYear() || +arrayDate[2] !== date.getMonth() || <same for date>`

Comment: I had this problem. Though not dupe, you will get help from this post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109765/javascript-date-validation

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks I made some modification to the code you gave, on adding the below to lines to the already existing code, it works as expected. I added the getMonth() + 1 since index for it starts from 0 for that function alone

`var valid = +arrayDate[3] === actualDate.getFullYear() && +arrayDate[2] === actualDate.getMonth() + 1 && +arrayDate[1] === actualDate.getDate();
print(valid);`

Comment: i hope this solves you problem. :-) also if you are open for library, you should look into moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example can help you:

```
var dateString = 'Mon Jun 24 2013 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
var myDate = new Date(dateString);
var final_date = myDate.getDate()+"-"+(myDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+myDate.getFullYear();
```

Here you can verify each variable as day, month and year.